# How to write Junit testcase for a class that is inside the actvity?

Tags: android, junit, gps

I have  class name`GPSLocationListener`  which is inside an Activiy and i want to test the method `onLocationChanged()`which is `GPSLocationListener` class method .so can i write the test case in the same Actvity or i have to create different test class for that `GPSLocationListener` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would strongly encourage you to make a separate test project for your current project.

Assuming you are using eclipse, simply right-click your current project --> New --> Other --> Under "Android" find "Android Test Project" and select the target project.

Now you can add a class to your test project and let it extend AndroidTestCase like so:

```
public class MainActivityTest extends AndroidTestCase {

    public void methodTest() {
        //Your method specific test here
    }

    public void testSanity() {
        assertEquals(2, 1 + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: thats correct but how can i write a junit test case method for a void method dont know what it will return at run time.just want to check whether the method is calling at the time of execution of program.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you just want to know if your method is actually called during runtime ? If so then just insert a breakpoint or am I missing some explanation ? Maybe try logging the result in LogCat ?